# Log4j Vulnerability in jetty jetty-hightide-7.6.1.v20120215/webapps/cometd.war

Tags: log4j, jetty, cometd, end-of-life

We are trying to mitigate the laetst log4j vulnerability in our application our scans show that **jetty-hightide-7.6.1.v20120215/webapps/cometd.war** is using the older version of log4j that is log4j.1 need help in ways to mitigate this.

Can we delete it from the webapps.

Comment: Ways:  1) Upgrade to a newer version of Jetty without the vulnerability. 2) Use standard techniques to patch the vulnerability.  3) Contact the people who supplied you with the software via your existing support arrangements.

Comment: 4) Read the CVEs and analyze how you have installed and are using the app to decide if the vulnerability is actually a risk for you.  5) Employ a consultant to advise you.

Comment: Can you delete the specific `cometd.war` file?  We can't tell you.  But if the cometd functionality is being used, then deleting it will probably break your server ... in some way.  Do some research about what `cometd.war` is actually providing ...

Comment: @StephenC unfortunately we will not be able to upgrade it to latest version . This cometd.war is present in webapps folder by default.

Comment: If you can't figure this out for yourself, your best course of action will be to employ a consultant to do it for you.  (Talk to your boss ....)

Comment: @vamsi Jetty 7 (what hightide 7 is based on) was declared EOL (End of Life) back in 2014.  Log4j 1.x was declared EOL back in 2015.  EOL means it is unsupported and will not receive updates, even security updates.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of jetty-hightide-7.6.1.v20120215 has far more vulnerabilities present than just cometd.

**Jetty 7.x**

Jetty 7.x was declared EOL (End of Life) back in 2014.

https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/security_reports.php

**Log4j 1.x**

Log4j 1.x was declared EOL back in 2015.

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/

Along with 10 years of security updates to the following other projects present in your ancient jetty-hightide archive.

- objectweb asm 3.1
- javax.annotations 1.1
- derby 10.6
- javax.activation 1.1
- glassfish mail 1.4
- sun el 1.0
- javax.el 2.1
- jstl 1.2
- jsp 2.1
- glassfish jasper 2.1
- glassfish taglibs 1.2
- eclipse jdt 3.7
- javax.transactions 1.1
- atomikos 3.7
- jna 3.2.2
- setuid native 7.6
- spring framework 2.5
- cometd 2.4.0.RC3
- jackson 1.9
- log4j 1.2
- bayeux 2.4
- dojo 1.7
- dojox 1.7
- dojiit 1.7
- jquery 1.6

Every one of the items listed above have security vulnerabilities associated with them in the past 10 years, every one of them need to be evaluated. (many of the vulnerabilities are actually quite severe, on par with the log4j one you are specifically chasing)